# I'm getting Call to undefined function wp_parse_list() out of the blue

Tags: errors, fatal-error

I woke up this morning and started getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_parse_list() in /app/public.built/wp-includes/class-wp-comment-query.php:485 Stack trace: #0 /app/public.built/wp-includes/class-wp-comment-query.php(395): WP_Comment_Query->get_comment_ids() #1 /app/public.built/wp-includes/class-wp-comment-query.php(346): WP_Comment_Query->get_comments() #2 /app/public.built/wp-includes/comment.php(242): WP_Comment_Query->query(Array) #3 /app/public.built/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-comments-list-table.php(147): get_comments(Array) #4 /app/public.built/wp-admin/edit-comments.php(140): WP_Comments_List_Table->prepare_items() #5 {main} thrown in /app/public.built/wp-includes/class-wp-comment-query.php on line 485

I upgraded from 5.0.3 to 5.1 yesterday evening. I use WP REST API and I'm not sure if its response was cached by the client being the reason of noticing this only today...

I don't even use the comments in WP. Can this be entirely turned off? Or has anyone experienced this? I'm afraid production cache will also expire and will go down soon. Thanks

**UPDATE:**
After downgrading back to 5.0.3 this has been resolved. However the question is still open.

Comment: and where do you get that error?

Comment: It sounds like there was an issue with the install of 5.1. Try reinstalling it.

Answer (score -1):

it looks like this is a new function since 5.1.0. see that info here: https://de.wpseek.com/function/wp_parse_list/

you could try to add this in your themes function.php temporarily, as a workaround.

```
function wp_parse_list( $list ) {
    if ( ! is_array( $list ) ) {
        return preg_split( '/[\s,]+/', $list, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
    }

    return $list;
}
```

so as you guess: i think it's something related with caching, too.